# django-allauth with multiple domains

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, multi-tenant, django-allauth

I am creating a web application that will support several domains.  For example, if my app were named `www.webapp.com`, I'd also have numerous customers mapping their domains to my site via DNS CNAME mappings, i.e. `webapp.yourdomain.com CNAME www.webapp.com` and `foo.anotherdomain.com CNAME www.webapp.com`, etc...

I want users to authenticate against my app via Google or Facebook (OAuth 2.0) - without me (or the domain owners) having to create a separate Google/Facebook app per mapped domain.  Ideally, I would have the base domain act as a broker and redirect to the appropriate mapped domain when responding to the callback url.  For example, a user visiting `webapp.yourdomain.com/accounts/facebook/login` would authenticate against Facebook with a callback url going to `www.webapp.com/accounts/facebook/login/callback`.  When processing the request, I could find the appropriate context, and redirect to `webapp.yourdomain.com/accounts/facebook/login/callback` where the real authentication would take place (and domain-specific auth cookies would be set).

So, is this doable in django-allauth?  How much hacking would it require?  Or, is there another social authentication solution for Django that would be easier to implement this in?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Django sites framework together with django-allauth.

> Consumer keys, tokens make use of the Django sites framework. This is
>   especially helpful for larger multi-domain projects, but also allows
>   for for easy switching between a development (localhost) and
>   production setup without messing with your settings and database.

Just configure each social app in the admin backend.